# Pass parameter to luigi config

Tags: luigi

I have a `luigi config` file and I want to supply somehow the name of the file, and want to construct several paths using it, so that not to edit it in multiple places there. The example config file:

https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/master/examples/config.toml

Is maybe showing it on line `14`, but even if it what I am looking for, it is unclear how I should supply a variable there. Can I just define it at the top and then use? I want to do smth like:

```
file_name = 'batch9'

[TaskName]
source_path = hdfs://[file_name].vcf
dest_path = hdfs://[file_name].mt

...
```

And possibly get it even from the calling command itself (although it is not absolutely necessary for me).

Answer (score 1):

Currently Luigi doesn't have a way to do this explicitly (I have wanted to do this as well). There are a couple ways around it however. One is that you can create your config as a template (which you already nearly have) and then build the template into a new file that you use your variable in. Then you export the new file as the file to use for configuration. All of this would happen in your main function before you build luigi or even any of the tasks you would execute.